# SlideToggle function refusing to work on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am making a php/ajax chat and am having some problems with using it on IE, everything works perfectly fine on Google Chrome, but on IE, the chat refuses to slide up when the header is clicked, I have a SlideToggle when the chatheader div is clicked which should toggle the chatcontainer to slide up just like the Facebook chat. Here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".chatheader").on("click", function () {
    $("#chatcontainer").slideToggle();
    $("#chatmessages").scrollTop($("#chatmessages")[0].scrollHeight);
});
</script>
```

Just to clarify, it works perfectly fine on google chrome, but refusing to work on IE, anyone know why it isn't working on IE and how to fix it?

Comment: What version of IE? Quirksmode suggests that prior IE 8 it's implemented incorrectly (ref: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html).

Comment: In which case that shouldn't be the problem... :/

Comment: check your console. you might see an error that can help you troubleshoot.